# How to get POI to evaluate and format a cell exactly as Excel does?

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi, evaluation

I'm trying to read an excel file using POI. I'm interested in the cell values exactly as they are displayed by Excel.

The cell can contain formulas that format numbers themselves (without using the normal cell formatting) but the behaviour of those is inconsistent in POI.

```
              Formula                Value in Excel   Value in POI
    =TEXT(1234,68; "#.##0,00")          1.234,68        1.234,68
    =TEXT("1234,68"; "#.##0,00")        1.234,68        #VALUE!
```

I cannot request the my users to make sure all their cells always use numeric values instead of string values, especially when in Excel there is no difference in the result value for input of either data type. Moreover, I would like to have consistent behaviour: POI should mimic Excel closely.

What am I missing?
I thought it might be locale related, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create((File)excelFile, null, true)) {
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(/*new Locale("nl", "BE")*/);
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateAll();

    Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: If you look at documentation [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) - please show "Technical Details", you will find "**value** A numeric value that you want to be converted into text." So `value` **must** be numeric per definition. Seems as if `Excel` itself is more tolerant as told in its own documentation. But then you cannot expect that `apache poi` will be as tolerant as well. It must follow the given documentation.

Comment: Looking into the implementation of the TEXT function, it seems that POI does try to convert the String value into a Double. For that, POIs`OperandResolver.parseDouble` method uses Javas own `Double.parseDouble` which only supports numeric Strings with the dot as the decimal separator. Excel probably uses the locale to know I use a decimal comma, that behaviour should in my opinion be consistent in POI. However, there is no way to change that in POI so I guess this question does not have a satisfying answer :(

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Probably best to submit an issue at [Apache POI Bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?list_id=165262&product=POI).

Comment: Bug created at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61874

Comment: Nice feature request (not really a bug in my opinion). But what locale shall POI take into account? `Excel` takes into account the locale of the operating system it runs on. But POI could run server side and the server could have a different locale than the client. So what then? What does "1,234" means then? Does it means `1.234` (1 and 234 thousandth) as of German locale or does it means `1,234` (1 thousand and 234) as of US locale?

Comment: POI could use the locale set by [LocaleUtil.setUserLocale](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleUtil.html#setUserLocale-java.util.Locale-).